# How to Create video from selected images of a folder using FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

For the time being I am doing

```
ProcessStartInfo ffmpeg = new ProcessStartInfo();
ffmpeg.CreateNoWindow = false;
ffmpeg.UseShellExecute = false;

ffmpeg.FileName = "e:\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe";
ffmpeg.Arguments = "for file in (D:\\Day\\*.jpg); do ffmpeg -i \"$file\" -vf fps=1/60 -q:v 3 \"D:\\images\\out.mp4\"; done;";
ffmpeg.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Process x = Process.Start(ffmpeg);
```

Here I'm getting exception saying system cannot find specified file.
For time being I'm considering all the files in D:\Day\*.jpg but actually I need to query individual files from a list.

Where am I wrong in the above scenario?

Comment: "e:\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe" maybe you need to escape those slashes?

Comment: it looks like you are trying to output one video for each frame, but you keep the same video name, so it will just get overwritten...

Comment: but I really have no idea what the hell: 
`ProcessStartInfo ffmpeg = new ProcessStartInfo();` is... maybe you should tag that... whatever it is (power shell or asp.net or whatever, I don't know, and most people looking at the ffmpeg tag are unix people)

Answer (score 1):

We need to create a separate text file with the image names and use that text file to create your video.

inside frameList.txt :

```
file 'D:\20180205_054616_831.jpg'
file 'D:\20180205_054616_911.jpg'
file 'D:\20180205_054617_31.jpg'
file 'D:\20180205_054617_111.jpg'
```

and in Arguments of the process use,

```
"-report -y -r 15/1 -f concat -safe 0 -i frameList.txt -c:v libx264 -s 1920*1080 -b:v 2000k -vf fps=15,format=yuv420p out.mp4"
```